# Do mod_rewrite rules work with website requested resources

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting

I am fairly new to URL rewriting and was curious as to whether patterns that are matched are applied to resources that are requested by the website (image, fonts, scripts, etc).

As an example, i know i can rewrite all requests from http to https using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

So if i my website was http://example.com, it would request https://example.com if i was to visit using the HTTP protocol.

Does this apply to resources that are requested via the website/browser such as internal images/fonts/assets that are hard coded with 'http://' links.

If not, why? how does a request made by a website to a resource with a hard coded link (http://) differ to the one when i input the address into my address bar. Does this mean if i have hundreds of hard coded links with the HTTP protocol, that i would have to go in manually and change them all to HTTPS?

If this is the case, do anchor tags to http:// get rewritten to https:// when i click on an internal link?

Comment: Nevermind i guess it doesn't work this way. This post answered my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112266/whats-correct-htaccess-rule-to-redirect-mixed-content-to-https

I guess to replace all links i could just recursively search the public directory and replace them with sed. I was misunderstanding mixed content warnings.

Comment: On protocol level there is obviously no difference between such requests. That is the whole idea behind the transport protocol: to be content agnostic. One note however for this specific case: hard coded http references are a _very_ bad idea (one should _always_ use _relative_ references), since every sane browser today will block requests to unencrypted URLs from a resource loaded via an encrypted request _for very good reasons_ . So a website with hard coded http references _is broken_ .